# SELECT where when Max of one field corresponding field in another is something

Tags: sql

If I have a table "table1" and the columns are:

```
EMAIL | USER_ID | START_DATE | CANCEL_DATE
```

If a person signs up into our database they appear once. If they cancel their account then they appear again and CANCEL_DATE is populated - so twice. If they then re-subscribe they appear 3 times and the new record has a new START_DATE.

So the table is at the subscription not account level.

If I wanted to pull a list of email addresses and user IDs of people that have cancelled and NOT since resubscribed I would need to (in plain English) to this:

1. Select all records (Emails and IDs) where there is at least 1 value in CANCEL_DATE (If they've never cancelled it's NULL)
2. Then, of those records only include ones where the CANCEL_DATE is not NULL when looking at the MAX of START_DATE.

How do I do this?

If it was excel I'd do a vlookup against max of start date looking at the cancel date column.

Hope I'm making sense?

- added later. I also need to add the condition that the final results should only include records where CANCEL_DATE < CURRENT_DATE

---

I think I got it using a sub query. Is the a cleaner way?

```
SELECT EMAIL, USER_ID FROM (
    SELECT EMAIL, GUID, CANCEL_DATE
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY EMAIL, USER_ID, CANCEL_DATE
    HAVING MAX(CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE) < MAX(SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE)
) base1
WHERE SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE < CURRENT_DATE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

START_DATE and CANCLE_DATE are mutually exclusive, only one populated, the other NULL?

```
select email, user_id
from table1
group by email, user_id
having max(START_DATE) > max(CANCEL_DATE)
```

This returns only active subscribers who cancelled and later subscribed again.

**Edit:**

As you seem to want the exact opposite you just have to change the condition:

```
select email, user_id
from table1
group by email, user_id
having max(START_DATE) < max(CANCEL_DATE)
```

This returns all currently cancelled subscribers.

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth the query runs, which is further than I was before. But the results set is smaller than I know it should be. Does that signal anything? I was expecting ~50k records but instead got 1.5k. I know that's not much info to go on but wonder if it signified somehting?

Comment: This is resubscribed users. I think the OP wants "all currently cancelled" subscribers. I guess just invert the comparison to max(CANCEL_DATE) > max(START_DATE).

Comment: @AndySavage: you're probably right, I need to change the condition.

Comment: The data set probably isn't large enough to care, but assuming (email, user_id) is the index then you could probably get a result even faster with `HAVING COUNT(*) % 2 = 0` as then it needs just an index scan without data. This is more fragile though - it's relying on correct data.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the helpful comments. I switched the operator around and the results seem to make sense now. But there's one more little detail I forgot to throw in. It's WHERE CANCEL_DATE is less than CURRENT_DATE. I tried adding this to the end (HAVING MAX(START_DATE) < MAX(CANCEL_DATE) AND CANCEL_DATE < CURRENT_DATE. This gave an error about non aggregate values. I then tried adding the new condition before the GROUP BY statement and the query ran but in theory that should not be correct - I need to add a where clause to the final results set.

Comment: You need to add an aggregate function on CANCEL_DATE in HAVING: (HAVING MAX(START_DATE) < MAX(CANCEL_DATE) AND MAX(CANCEL_DATE) < CURRENT_DATE

Comment: Ah! There we go it's making sense now. Thanks (again) @dnoeth